# Why does this node.js Buffer contain random values?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to create a node.js Buffer that contains 'x'throughout.

```
function createBuffer(buffer_size)
{
    var buf = new Buffer(buffer_size);
    var i;
    for (i=0;i<buffer_size;i++)
    {
        buf.write('x');
    }

    return buf;
}

var testbuf = createBuffer(5);
console.log(testbuf);
```

The console result is;

```
<Buffer 78 d3 f6 21 7c>
```

Why does Buffer contain random values when `'x'` is written to the Buffer?

Comment: It doesn't answer my question. In my case, I am assigning the same value throughout. Yet, the buffer shows different value.

Comment: Why the negative vote? What is wrong with the question?

Comment: Yeah, in retrospect, you're right, not a duplicate. Sorry about that! That said, I think the issue is that you're not writing to a particular offset of the buffer, so you're just writing `x` to the first byte 5 times - I think you need to call `buffer.write("x", i)` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are writing to default offset i.e `0` again and again.
you should use

```
buff.write('x',i); //this will increment the offset
```

What you are getting is some garbage value on other offsets.